# Вместо fragment_gallery.xml отображается content_main.xml

Tags: java, android

Появилась проблема, что интересного - я не придумал как её объяснить. Поэтому прикрепляю скриншот. fragment_gallery в самом Android studio отображается корректно, а вот в приложении при заходе на страницу fragment_gallery отображение вообще content_main. И такое со всеми вкладками (вроде fragment_slideshow) Код не прикрепляю, примерно опишите.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: примерно сложно, покажите код, по логике если все правильно подключили то все должно правильно отображаться

Comment: Код activity_main?

Comment: прикрепите код fragment_gallery и всего что у вас взывает вопросы, потому что имея только картинку помочь сложно

Comment: На самом делем там отображается не content_main, а его элементы, в моем случае - ImageButton.